# Low migration rate in Papadopoulou et al. (2008)

Tags: population-genetics

In the paper "Speciation and DNA barcodes: testing the effects of dispersal on the formation of discrete sequence clusters" by Papadopoulou et al. (2008), is there an explanation as to why the authors simulated very low migration rates ($m$ between $10^{-8}-5\times 10^{-5}$)? The population size was 160,000, which produces $Nm$ between 0.0001-0.5. This is much less that a single migrant per generation.

Any insight would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick look-up, they don't seem to comment much on this choice of parameter unfortunately. Here are my quick thoughts.

They are dealing with quasi isolated species. They explored a range of values and I would like to assume that made sure that more extreme values won't yield to drastically different results.

These simulations can be pretty computationally intensive, it is possible that they considered $Nm$ to be the important statistic but they would assume that the results could scale up and down for different $N$ and $m$ values. In fact, they almost systematically refer to their migration rate as $Nm$.